# How do I stop panning when moving a node ? Limit zooming too ? D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've added a pan/zoom element to my force directed graph. It only works when I'm over a node.

What I wish to happen is when I click a node, the panning stops so I can move the node. But when on the 'background' so to speak I can move the graph around.

Also, I need the ability to zoom in all the time on or off the graph using the mouse wheel but also have a boundary on the zoom ? To get around this would I have to limit the scale in some way ?

__________________________________________________Fixed

Ive sorted it by calling the redraw() elsewhere. I have my 'SVG' then i have my 'inner' ontop of that. So i call the redraw on the SVG and now it works only when im off the nodes, which is alot better than only working on the nodes.

I think this is due to when i call it in the 'inner', as my 'inner' is just the graph the mouse position isn't being recognised as being in the 'inner'. So when i move it to the layer behind it, the 'SVG' it works fine as my SVG is a 'canvas' where everything is in. So the mouse position now interacts with the SVG, thus calling the 'redraw'.

Am i correct in saying this ?

Comment: You can limit the zoom the following way: svg.call(zoom.on("zoom", redraw).scaleExtent([0.5, 2]))

Comment: Please answer your own question instead of editing your question with a possible answer. Also, providing an example with a small code snippet might help make your question easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your zoom to only trigger on the background, then you can create a "rect" element and call the zoom behavior from that rect element. If this element is appended to your SVG canvas before appending anything else (or inserted beneath them) then when you click and drag on the background (the rect) you'll get panning and zooming but when you click and drag on anything drawn above it, you get the behavior associated with those elements.

The rect should have the size and width of your SVG canvas and a fill-opacity of 0 so that it's invisible.